# create stored select procedure oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

everyone, I have an oracle 11g DB, I want to create a stored procedure that returns a select statement between some view and a table as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE schemaName.my_PROC_name (p1 in number(10))
as 
begin 
select v.*,(select column1 from table t where t.id=p1) from view v ;
end my_PROC_name ;
```

and it doesn't work, I'm not familiar with oracle DB so pleas if any help!

Comment: Just saying "it doesn't work" isn't generally very helpful. A procedure can't *return* anything (though it can have OUT parameters), only a function can. In later versions there are some enhancements, but those won't help you on 11g. You have to select *info* something or use a cursor. But why do you want to use PL/SQL here at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- if you want to retrieve columns from more than one data sources( such
  as tables or views ), the you'd better to use join clauses among them
  rather than using subqueries, in which there may arise `single subquery returns more than one row` error.
- The precision for a data type is not allowed during the definition of
  the parameters for procedures, functions or packages. (replace `p1 in number(10)` with `p1 number`)
- `view` and `table` are reserved keywords and they're not allowed to be
  used during the creation of them.
- you would need to return the values from the query to some variables.
  For which and `into` clause would be needed, and `out` type
  parameters would be needed to take them out of the such programming
  units
- using `in`(default) for variable declaration, and using the procedure
  name after the `end` clause is redundant. To specify the element type, use `%TYPE` to provide the datatype of a variable or database column as much as you can rather than specifying independent data types.
- Sometimes, you may not able to retrieve the desired data, don't
  forget to add exception handling for your queries for those
  situations against getting error messages.

So, the following code block might be considered for your case :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_PROC_name(  
                                          i_p1       NUMBER, 
                                          o_col0 OUT myview.col0%type, 
                                          o_col1 OUT mytable.column1%type 
                                        ) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT v.col0, t.column1 
      INTO o_col0, o_col1
      FROM myview v
      LEFT JOIN mytable t 
        ON v.id = t.v_id
     WHERE t.id = i_p1;
   EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN null;
             WHEN too_many_rows THEN null;      
END;
/
```

and you can execute the procedure as

```
SQL> set serveroutput on

SQL> declare
  i_p1 number := 3; 
  o_1  myview.col0%type;  
  o_2  mytable.column1%type;     
begin 
  my_proc_name(i_p1,o_1,o_2); 
  dbms_output.put_line(o_1||' - '||o_2);
end;
/
```

Comment: Is recommending squashing exceptions really a good idea (esp. to a new user)? The original query doesn't suggest any relationship between the view or the table, so would alway return multiple rows (unless the view only had one of course!), making a ref cursor perhaps a better `out` parameter type; with your added relation variables may be OK, but you'd probably still like to know why you got no data back. (Also not sure why you've added a nested block; and I'd say having `end my_proc_name` was good practice, at least within a package; but those might be more a personal taste thing... *8-)

Comment: thenk you for the declarative recommendations @AlexPoole .

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan i created it but now i'm faceing a problem in execution i googled but nothing, i use the following command : execute procName ('in parameter value');